# Why is my onChange trigger running without changes? (Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1)

Tags: exception, onchange

I have one form response spreadsheet and I am importing a subset of the rows into separate sheets for four different worksites. This routes the responses to the appropriate staff. The worksite sheets are populated with a Query and ImportRange formula.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xyzurl","A1:J"),"where Col8='Southwest Community Center' OR Col9='Southwest Community Center'")
```

Each worksite sheet has identical script with an onChange trigger to run when there's an update to the sheet. The script runs through the rows that have not yet been processed, sends an email, and then updates the processed rows with a 'Sent' flag.

```
function sendEmail(){

 //setup function
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,12);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
 var message = "";

 //iterate loop
 for (i in AllValues) {

  //set current row
  var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

  //define column to check if sent (starts from "0" not "1")
  var EmailSent = CurrentRow[10];

  //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
  if (EmailSent == "sent") 
     continue;

    //set HTML template for information
    message =
    "<p>The swimmer below is interested in your site pool. Please email to schedule a tryout. Thank you!</p><br>" +  
      "<p><b>Parent Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Email Address: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Swimmer Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Swimmer Age: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Swimming Experience: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>High-Level Meet Experience: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Other Notes: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p>";

    //set the row to look at
    var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

    //mark row as "sent"
    ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 11).setValue("sent");

    //send the actual email  
    var SendTo = "coach-swcc@swimpac.org";
    var Subject = "TRYOUT REQUEST (Southwest)";
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
    });

}

};
```

It seems to be working as expected except...

Yesterday there were no changes in any of the worksheets and I got email messages saying "Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1." I think this means that the code is running, finding that all the rows have already been processed, leaving an empty range to throw an error. I must be misunderstanding something. Any insights?

Comment: Do I need to use SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXX') instead SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSheet() ?